# How to reset Cascading DropDownList for Ajax Control Toolkit to its default prompt text (server side)?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, cascadingdropdown

How to reset Cascading DropDownList for Ajax Control Toolkit to its default prompt text (server side)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset dropdownlist to its default prompt text using `PromptValue` property.

```
ddl.SelectedValue = ddl.PromptValue;
```